# How to export a div (holding many separate gifs/webp) as a single webp/gif?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Perplexity chat summary](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/580e8a37-d477-4346-a90e-3d5cd58825d7?s=c)

This thread discusses how to create a 1000x1000 pixel canvas or div with a white background and gray background for the page. The thread also covers how to add a 10x10 pixel GIF to the top left corner of the canvas or div and how to fill the container with the GIF. Additionally, the thread explains how to add a button to save the container as a single GIF. The code provided uses the html2canvas library to capture the container as a canvas element and the GIF library to create a GIF from the canvas element. The thread also discusses the possibility of converting the container from a div to a canvas element to create the GIF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: gray;
      }
      .container {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
      }
      .gif {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .button-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .save-button {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: #4caf50;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button class="save-button">Save as GIF</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const container = document.querySelector(".container");

      const img = new Image();
      img.src = "https://gifdb.com/images/high/mlg-dark-souls-video-game-play-z2y2ghg4nj1upfym.webp";
      img.onload = function () {
        const gifWidth = 10;
        const gifHeight = 10;
        const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
        const containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
        const numCols = Math.ceil(containerWidth / gifWidth);
        const numRows = Math.ceil(containerHeight / gifHeight);

        for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            const gif = document.createElement("img");
            gif.src = img.src;
            gif.classList.add("gif");
            gif.style.top = i * gifHeight + "px";
            gif.style.left = j * gifWidth + "px";
            container.appendChild(gif);
          }
        }
      };

        const saveButton = document.querySelector(".save-button");
        saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
          html2canvas(container).then(function (canvas) {
            const gif = new GIF({
              workers: 2,
              quality: 10,
              width: canvas.width,
              height: canvas.height,
            });
            gif.addFrame(canvas, { delay: 100 });
            gif.render();
            const img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(gif.blob);
            document.body.appendChild(img);
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
updated code html file: 


<head>

  <!-- Include html2canvas library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include gif.js library -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jnordberg/gif.js/v0.2.0/dist/gif.js"></script>
</head>

updated code js :

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="save-button">Save as GIF</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://gifdb.com/images/high/mlg-dark-souls-video-game-play-z2y2ghg4nj1upfym.webp";
    img.onload = function () {
      const gifWidth = 10;
      const gifHeight = 10;
      const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
      const containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
      const numCols = Math.ceil(containerWidth / gifWidth);
      const numRows = Math.ceil(containerHeight / gifHeight);

      for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
          const gif = document.createElement("img");
          gif.src = img.src;
          gif.classList.add("gif");
          gif.style.top = i * gifHeight + "px";
          gif.style.left = j * gifWidth + "px";
          container.appendChild(gif);
        }
      }
    };

    const saveButton = document.querySelector(".save-button");
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      // Use html2canvas to capture the entire container div as an image
      html2canvas(container).then(function (canvas) {
        // Use gif.js to create a GIF from the canvas
        const gif = new GIF({
          workers: 2,
          quality: 10,
          width: canvas.width,
          height: canvas.height,
        });

        // Add the canvas as a frame to the GIF
        gif.addFrame(canvas, { delay: 100 });

        // Render the GIF
        gif.render();

        // Create an image element and set its source to the generated GIF
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(gif.blob);

        // Append the image to the document body
        document.body.appendChild(img);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: not working bud. still the button is useless

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).